# How to include an id in the nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-form-for

I have a nested form ,and i want to include city_id in the stores model,is this `<%= s.hidden_field :city_id, @city.id %>` correct? If yes what do i add in the controller after that? If it is not a correct way to include it can anybody show me the right way  please? Much thanks.

```
<%= form_for @deal ,:url=>{:action =>"create"} do |c|%>
  <%= c.text_field :item_name %>
  <%= c.text_field :price %>

  <%=c.fields_for :stores do |s| %>
    <%=s.text_field :store_name %>
    <%= s.hidden_field :city_id, @city.id %>
    <%=s.text_field :address %>
  <%end%>           

  <%= c.submit "post"%>     
<%end%>
```

**controller**

```
def create
  @city = City.find(session[:city_id])
  @deal=@city.deals.build(params[:deal])

  if @deal.save
    redirect_to @deal
    flash[:notice]="successfully created"
  else
    render 'new' 
  end 
end
```

**models**

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :stores
    has_many :deals 
end

class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :city
    has_many :stores ,:through =>:store_deals
    has_many :store_deals
end

class StoreDeal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :store
    belongs_to :deal
end
```

**error**

```
NoMethodError in Deal#new

Showing /home/Deals/app/views/deal/new.html.erb where line #13 raised:

undefined method `merge' for 2:Fixnum
Extracted source (around line #13):

10: <tr><td><label>Price</label></td><td><%= c.text_field :price %></td></tr>
11: <%=c.fields_for :stores do |s| %>
12: <tr><td><label>Store</label></td><td><%=s.text_field :store_name %></td></tr>
13: <%= s.hidden_field :city_id, @city.id %>
14: <tr><td><label>Cross street</label></td><td><%=s.text_field :address %></td></tr>
15: <%end%>
16: <tr><td><%= c.submit "post"%></td></tr>
```

Comment: You need to explain what the issue is. Are you getting an error? Unexpected behavior? I can't tell right off the bat what is wrong, but you also haven't given us sufficient code examples. The relevant models, as well as the controller action where that form is being called, would help.

Comment: @bricker I have added the models ,I get undefined method `merge' for 2:Fixnum..... let me know what other info do you need.Thank you

Comment: bricker's question is good.  Usually when I find myself using hidden fields in rails forms it's an indication of something I should be doing differently, i.e. 'the rails way' to avoid usage.  This is why more info on what you are trying to achieve may be helpful :)

Comment: @katie where is the error occurring? Please update your question with the full error.

Comment: @bricker I have updated the error.Basically there is city_id column in the stores table,I need to know how to grab it in the field while fetching stores table attribute data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, now that I've looked over your code more carefully and seen the it's clear what the problem is. The `hidden_field` helper doesn't have `value` as one of its arguments. Use:

```
<%= s.hidden_field :city_id, :value => @city.id %>
```

However, for the reason Michael Durrant points out, it would be better to handle this in your controller.

Comment: Thank you alot!How do you handle it in the controller?

Comment: Just fetch the city in the controller and merge that into the params hash.